# Threaded Video Player sync

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

**Disclaimer:I asked this question a few days ago [on codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75039/threaded-video-player-sync),but got no answer.Here I change the question format from review request to a specific problems.**

I am developing a video player with the following design:

The main thread - is GUI thread (Qt SDK).

Second thread - player thread which accepts commands from the GUI thread to play, forward, backward, stop etc. Now,this thread runs in a constant loop and and uses mutexes and wait conditions to live in sync with the main thread commands.

I have 2 problems with this code:

I don't feel my design is completely correct:I am using both mutex locks and atomic variables.I wonder if I can stay only with the atomics and use locks only for setting the wait conditions.

I am experiencing inconsistent bugs(probably due to the condition race when the play command tries to lock mutex which is already locked by the thread while the play loop is working) when I run "play" commands which activates a loop inside the thread loop. So I suppose it blocks the access to the shared variables to the main thread.

I have stripped off the code from unneeded stuff and it generally goes like this:

```
  void PlayerThread::drawThread()//thread method passed into new boost::thread
{

   //some init goes here....

      while(true)
      {
          boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
          m_event.wait(lock); //wait for event

          if(!m_threadRun){
             break; //exit the tread
          }

           ///if we are in playback mode,play in a loop till interrupted:
          if(m_isPlayMode == true){

              while(m_frameIndex < m_totalFrames && m_isPlayMode){

                       //play
                       m_frameIndex ++;

              }

               m_isPlayMode = false;

          }else{//we are in a single frame play mode:

               if(m_cleanMode){ ///just clear the screen with a color

                       //clear the screen from the last frame
                       //wait for the new movie to get loaded:

                       m_event.wait(lock); 


                       //load new movie......

               }else{ //render a single frame:

                       //play single frame....

               }


          }


      }

}
```

Here are the member functions of the above class which send commands to the thread loop:

```
void PlayerThread::PlayForwardSlot(){
//   boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if(m_cleanMode)return;
    m_isPlayMode = false;
    m_frameIndex++;
     m_event.notify_one();
}

 void PlayerThread::PlayBackwardSlot(){
 //  boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
  if(m_cleanMode)return;
   m_isPlayMode = false;
   m_frameIndex-- ;
   if(m_frameIndex < 0){
       m_frameIndex = 0;
   }

    m_event.notify_one();

 }


 void PlayerThread::PlaySlot(){
 // boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
   if(m_cleanMode)return;
   m_isPlayMode = true;
   m_event.notify_one(); //tell thread to  start playing.

  }
```

All the flag members like **m_cleanMode**, **m_isPlayMode** and **m_frameIndex** are atomics:

```
  std::atomic<int32_t>   m_frameIndex;
  std::atomic<bool>      m_isPlayMode; 
  std::atomic<bool>      m_cleanMode;
```

The  questions summary::

1. Do I need mutex locks when using atomics?
2. Do I set waiting in the correct place inside the while loop of the
   thread?
3. Any suggestion of a better design?

**UPDATE:**

Though I got an answer which seems to be  in the right direction I don't really understand it.Especially the pseudo-code part which is talking about service.It is completely unclear to me how it would work.I would like to get a more elaborated answer.It is also strange that I received only one constructive answer to such a common problem.So I am resetting the bounty.

Comment: Michael, in case you didn't know qt has its own mutex, condition, etc classes, eg `QMutex`, `QReadWriteLock`, `QWaitCondition`

Comment: Also, in qt you can send signals across threads, which in some cases can help avoid use locks altogether

Comment: @InnocentBystander yeah,I am aware but I was already using Boost thread API and had zero time to learn properly Qt's related API.

Comment: I did the exact same thing(playing mp3 files though, I did the decoding my self) some years ago in windows using c. I had three threads: main gui, processing messages from gui, decoding the mp3. The trick in  multithreading is to isolate as much as possible the threads from each other. All the variables where isolated(that was my main goal to avoid problems) and I had only one *lock*: writing and reading from a message queue. The writing was performed from the main gui and the reading from the thread processing messages.

Comment: The queue was an array of structs. Each struct had information about what to be performed eg play, stop, pause, next song, title of song etc. The main gui added a new message to the queue and the processing thread removed the messages. It worked with no problems mainly because I had no shared variables. Only one lock. Hope it helps.

Comment: @MichaelIV, where'd the +200 bounty go???

Comment: I guess it will go to  the dude with Qt based solution which looks much more simple and natural to the environment.The UmNyobe answer is great but I didn't really understand it to the end and he didn't want to supply more details.But  @UmNyobe definitely  deserves Bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestion of a better design?

Yes! Since you are using Qt I would heavily suggest to use Qt's eventloop (apart from the UI stuff this is IMO one of the main selling points of that library) and asynchronous signal/slots to do the controlling instead of your homegrown synchronization, which - as you found out - is a very fragile undertaking.

The main change this will bring to your current design is that you will have to do your video logic as part of the Qt event-loop, or, easier, just do a `QEventLoop::processEvents`. For that you will need a `QThread`. 
 Then it's very straightforward: You create some class that inherits from `QObject` let's say `PlayerController` which should contain signals like `play`, `pause`, `stop` and a class `Player` which will have slots `onPlay`, `onPause`, `onStop` (or without the on, your preference). Then create a 'controller' object of the `PlayerController` class in the GUI thread and the `Player` object in the 'video' thread (or use `QObject::moveToThread`). This is important, as Qt has the notion of thread affinity to determine in which thread SLOTs are executed. No connect the objects by doing `QObject::connect(controller, SIGNAL(play()), player, SLOT(onPlay()))`. Any call now to `PlayerController:play` on the 'controller' from the GUI thread will result in the `onPlay` method of the 'player' being executed in the *video thread* on the next event loop iteration. That's where you can then change your boolean status variables or do other kind of action without the need for explicit synchronization as your variables are only changes from the video thread now.

So something along those lines:

```
class PlayerController: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void play();
    void pause();
    void stop();
}

class Player: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void play() { m_isPlayMode = true; }
    void pause() { m_isPlayMode = false; }
    void stop() { m_isStop = true; };

private:
    bool m_isPlayMode;
    bool m_isStop;
}

class VideoThread: public QThread {

public:
    VideoThread (PlayerController* controller) {
        m_controller = controller;
    }

protected:
    /* override the run method, normally not adviced but we want our special eventloop */
    void run() {
        QEventLoop loop;
        Player* player = new Player;

        QObject::connect(m_controller, SIGNAL(play()), player, SLOT(play()));
        QObject::connect(m_controller, SIGNAL(pause()), player, SLOT(pause()));
        QObject::connect(m_controller, SIGNAL(stop()), player, SLOT(stop()));

        m_isStop = false;
        m_isPlayMode = false;
        while(!m_isStop) {
            // DO video related stuff
            loop.processEvents();
        }
    }


private:
    PlayerController* m_controller;
}



// somewhere in main thread
PlayerController* controller = new PlayerController();
VideoThread* videoThread = new VideoThread(controller);
videoThread.start();
controller.play();
```

Answer (score 6):

The biggest issue with your code is that you wait unconditionally. [boost::condition::notify_one ***only*** wake up a thread which is **waiting**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582643/1122645). Which means `Forward Step\Backward Step` then `Play` if fast enough will ignore the play command. I dont get `clean mode`, but you need at least

```
if(!m_isPlayMode)
{
     m_event.wait(lock);
}
```

In your code stop and stepping to a frame are virtually the same thing .You may want to use a tristate `PLAY,STEP, STOP` to be able to use the recommended way of waiting on a condition variable

```
while(state == STOP)
{
    m_event.wait(lock);
}
```

> ***1. Do I need mutex locks when using atomics?***

Technically yes. In this specific case I don't think so. 
Current races conditions (I noticed) :

- playing mode, playforward and playbackward will not result in the same `m_frameIndex` depending whether or not `drawThread` is within the `while(m_frameIndex < m_totalFrames && m_isPlayMode)` loop. Indeed `m_frameIndex`could be incremented once or twice (playforward).
- Entering the playing state in `PlaySlot` can be ignored if `drawThread` execute `m_isPlayMode = false;` before receiving the next event. Right now it is a non-issue because it will only happen if `m_frameIndex < m_totalFrames` is false. If `PlaySlot` was modifying `m_frameIndex` then you will have case of pushing play and nothing happen.

> ***2. Do I set waiting in the correct place inside the while loop of the thread?***

I would suggest to have only one wait in your code, for simplicity. And be explicit about the next thing to do using specific commands :

```
 PLAY, STOP, LOADMOVIE, STEP
```

> ***3. Any suggestion of a better design?***

Use an explicit event queue. You can use one which is Qt-based (require Qthreads) or boost based. The one based on boost use a `boost::asio::io_service` and a `boost::thread`.

You start the event loop using :

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
//permanent work so io_service::exec doesnt terminate immediately.
boost::asio::io_service::work work(service); 
boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::exec, boost::ref(service)));
```

Then you send your commands from the GUI using

```
MYSTATE state;
service.post(boost::bind(&MyObject::changeState,this, state));
```

- Your play method should request another play given that the state hasn't changed, rather than looping. It allows a better user preemption.
- Your step method should request a stop before displaying the frame.

Pseudocode:

```
play()
{
 if(state != PLAYING)
   return;
 drawframe(index);
 index++;
 service.post(boost::bind(&MyObject::play, this));
}

stepforward()
{
 stop();
 index++;
 drawframe(index);
}

stepbackward()
{
 stop();
 index--;
 drawframe(index);
}
```

**Edit:**
There is ***only one player thread*** which is created once and execute only ***one event loop***. Is is equivalent to  QThread::start(). The thread will live as long as the loop doesnt return, which is going to be till the `work` [object is destroyed OR when you explicitly stop the service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html). When you request to stop a service all posted tasks which are still pending are going to be executed first. You can interrupt the thread for fast exit if neccessary.

When there is a call for an action you post in the event loop ran by the player thread.

**Note:** You will probably need share pointers for the service and the thread. You will also need to put interrupt points in the play method in order to allow stopping the thread cleanly during playback. You don't need as much atomic as before. You don't need a condition variable anymore.

Comment: Interesting approach.Could you extend  a little bit on the interrupt points,given Boost API is used?Btw,cleanMode is when I load another footage to play.So it is kind of a point where all the currently used resources by the player thread are cleaned and reset.

Comment: Also,why do I need while(state == STOP)
{
    m_event.wait(lock);
}  ? in my loop after each rendered frame the thread is entering the waiting state unless it is being played in an inner loop.

Comment: for interrupt points see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption.predefined_interruption_points). For instance you can explicitly use `boost::this_thread::interruption_point();` as an interrupt point.

Comment: I recommend a `stop` state different from `step` just to make the code easier. It allows simpler algorithms. It allows you to use fewer shared variables between the caller and receiving threads. You only have one waiting thread here so using `while` doesnt give benefit (but doesnt hurt either).

Comment: Am I correct to say you are proposing to create new player thread each time there is a call for action?In what context drawFrame is invoked?Mind that I use OpenGL context in the player thread which must be there during the whole life time of the player.So this is not practical to recreate it on each player invocation.

Comment: I still don't understand how my new thread loop must look based on your remarks

Comment: I mean,you wrote here  stop() and drawFrame() methods.What are those?How do they interact with the player thread?Please supply a more detail example case of the full cycle.Also,the paradigm here is not producer-consumer as the main thread doesn't consume anything from the player except of some notification.The player thread both prepares data and renders it to GL viewport.Thanks!

Comment: I really wish I could mark your question as correct.I believe it is correct.But I don't completely understand what you mean.I asked you to elaborate but you didn't.I am going to reopen this question again.

Answer (score 0):

> 3. Any suggestion of a better design?

Instead of using separate thread, use `QTimer` and play on the main thread. No atomics or mutexes needed. I am not quite tracking with `m_cleanMode`, so I mostly took it out of the code. If you elaborate more on what it does, I cam add it to the code.

```
class Player
{
    int32_t m_frameIndex;
    bool m_cleanMode;

    QTimer m_timer;

    void init();
    void drawFrame();

slots:
    void play();
    void pause();
    void playForward();
    void playBackward();

private slots:
    void drawFrameAndAdvance();
}

void Player::init()
{
    // some init goes here ...

    m_timer.setInterval(333); // 30fps
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(drawFrameAndAdvance()));
}

void Player::drawFrame()
{
    // play 1 frame
}

void Player::drawFrameAndAdvance()
{
    if(m_frameIndex < m_totalFrames - 1) {
        drawFrame();
        m_frameIndex++;
    }
    else m_timer.stop();
}

void PlayerThread::playForward()
{
    if(m_cleanMode) return;

    m_timer.stop(); // stop playback
    if(m_frameIndex < m_totalFrames - 1) {
        m_frameIndex++;
        drawFrame();
    }
}

void PlayerThread::playBackward()
{
    if(m_cleanMode)return;

    m_timer.stop(); // stop playback
    if(m_frameIndex > 0) {
        m_frameIndex--;
        drawFrame();
    }
}

void PlayerThread::play()
{
    if(m_cleanMode) return;
    m_timer.start(); // start playback
}

void PlayerThread::pause()
{
    if(m_cleanMode) return;
    m_timer.stop(); // stop playback
}
```

Comment: My rationale to use separate thread is because there is a lot of stuff going on there which is synchronous.Some of the processing may become heavy as I don't just decode video but also do some image processing.That's why I must have it all  concurrent to the GUI thread where I want the UI stay responsive.